# My website isn't loading on SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I bought a postitivessl certificate from namecheap and I followed all the instructions but when I try to load my site with https:// in front of it, it doesn't load (Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) however when I just use http:// my site loads fine.

These are the tutorials I followed:

1. [Creation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-6)
2. [Installation](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1203)

Here is the main snippet from the code in my ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName mydomain.com:443

SSLEngine on

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apache.key 

SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/mydomain.ca-bundle
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My normal though process when I see something like this would be:

- Is the firewall off, or is port 443 open? (iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT would be the command to open it on most Linux distros). If yes...
- Is Apache actually listening on 443? (netstat -a will show you your listening ports). If yes...
- Is the browser trying to connect to a subdomain (like www). Adding the following to your config would help: serveralias *.mydomain.com

Additionally, I would check your apache logs for any possible errors.

Comment: Ok I did all of that. Still nothing. Nothing in the error logs relates to SSL or HTTPS unfortunately. If I go direct ip (https:// IP) it works.

Comment: That sounds like it could be the vhost setup in apache or that the client computer is not resolving the address to the server (but you wouldn't be able to use http:// host name).  Try removing the :443 from the servername directive. I will check into other possible reasons this may occur.

Comment: Very interesting!  If that server will be used for only one domain, you could try adding the hash (#) in front of ServerName mydomain.com and serveralias *.mydomain.com to comment them out.  This will tell apache to not use name-based virtual hosting.  I looked at your links for creation and installation and looked at the ssl.conf file on a CentOS virtual machine, and they should work as is.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out but again no luck with that :(

Comment: No worries.  I hope we can get it working for you.  This is the bare ssl.conf file from my VM: [http://pastebin.com/98bh1sW4](http://pastebin.com/98bh1sW4) for reference to what you have versus the default setup.  From the client, you should be able to ping the server, so the name is resolving to the server.  

I tried it on my VM, and came across more firewall issues.  I found the correct commands, and they are at [http://pastebin.com/dkFUU0Se](http://pastebin.com/dkFUU0Se).